# How do I create a linear regression graph using Matplotlib, pandas, and sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to create linear regression graph using Matplotlib, pandas, and sklearn. However, it does not seem to be working and I am not sure why.

[image]

Comment: You have two problems ① as noted by Quang Hoang you must sort both vectors and ② your predictions look wrong, I can see many couples of points with very close abscissae and wildly differing ordinates and this is not the outcome of a linear model…

Answer (score 0):

You could sort `goldEarned` and plot:

```
order = np.argsort(goldEarned.ravel())

plt.plot(goldEarned[order], kills_preds[order])
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem can be also to plot a new line with the information of the linear regression fit! You will have some weights w1[x1] + w2[x2] ... +b (intercept). Supposing you only have one feature in the X array (kills) ( only one column ). You will get a simple line equation consisting of y = w1[x1] +b. In this equation  y: target or/and prediction, x1 is the feature, and b the intercept. So just plot it :
If you have any more doubts, I suggest you check out sci-kit's learn documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

```
points = np.linspace(np.min(kills), np.max(kills), 100)  # create an array from original array

w1 = linreg.coef_ # save the coefficient of linear regression into w1
b = linreg.intercept_ # save the intercept of linear regression
#### add plot to your data scatter plot 
plt.plot(points, (points*w1)+b , linestyle = '-', label = "fit")
```

Comment: I got confused, your X axis should be gold_earned so just modify the points array so that it takes min and max from goldearned